# Why does my vector print out all zeroes?

Tags: c++, vector

I have this preliminary code:

```
#include "std_lib_facilities_4.h"

void numbers()
{
    vector<int> first(9);
    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; ++i)
    {
            cout << i << endl;
            first.push_back(i);
    }
    for (int j = 0; j <= 9; ++j)
            cout << first[j];
}

int main()
{
        numbers();
}
```

I was hoping to get the number 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, and 9 to print out when I printed each element. Instead I get this:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
0000000000
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is std_lib_facilities_4.h?

Comment: Oh, sorry I should have mentioned that. std_lib_facilites_4.h is an edited version of the normal std_lib_facilites.h that my professor made specifically for my C++ class. It's basically the same as far as I know with a few changes.

Comment: What is a normal `std_lib_facilites.h`?

Comment: @Nabla: Likely the one from Bjarne Stroustrup's book: http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/std_lib_facilities.h

Answer (score 5):

You're initializing the vector with 9 empty values (`0`) and then pushing back 10 *new* values (the first of which is `0`), yielding a vector of 19 elements, the first 10 of which are all still 0. This is what `first(9)` does, creates a vector of 9 elements.

Instead of `push_back`, just set the element to the new value:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 9; ++i)
    first[i] = i;
```

Comment: 0 <= i<= 9 is 10 iterations, so in total the vector will have 19 elements, not 18.

Answer (score 2):

Did you realize that `first` will be size of `19`? And the first `9` values will all be `0`.

The reason is that `vector<int> first(9);` initializes it with size `9` with all values `0`. Then in the `for` loop, each time you do `push_back()`, you are adding a new value (make its size `+1`) to it.

**Two solutions:**

1. Change

   ```
   vector<int> first(9);
   ```

   to

   ```
   vector<int> first;
   ```
2. Alternatively, change

   ```
   vector<int> first(9);
   ...
   first.push_back(i);
   ```

   to

   ```
   vector<int> first(10);
   ...
   first[i] = i;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `push_back` a new element is added to the vector, so you start with 9 zeros in it and then add the numbers from 0 to 9 AFTER the zeros.

`push_back` works by adding the specified element and increasing the vector size by one.

The number you pass with creating a vector is the initial size and, for a vector of int, all the values will be initially 0.

Answer (score 0):

At first you created a vector with 9 elements which was initialized by 0 if you did not explicitly specify an initializer yourself

```
vector<int> first(9);
```

So now vector first contains 9 elements each of which is initialized by 0.

Then you add new 10 elements at the end of the vector using method push_back

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 9; ++i)
{
        cout << i << endl;
        first.push_back(i);
}
```

So now the vector contains 9 initial zeroes and then  0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9. That is its first 10 elements are equal to 0.

And in this loop

```
for (int j = 0; j <= 9; ++j)
        cout << first[j];
```

you output the first 10 elements that is ten zeroes.

If you want to have only 10 elements in the vector then you could write either

```
void numbers()
{
    vector<int> first;
    first.reserve( 10 );

    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; ++i)
    {
            cout << i << endl;
            first.push_back(i);
    }
    for (int j = 0; j <= 9; ++j)
            cout << first[j];
}
```

or

```
void numbers()
{
    vector<int> first( 10 );

    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; ++i)
    {
            cout << i << endl;
            first[i] = i;
    }
    for (int j = 0; j <= 9; ++j)
            cout << first[j];
}
```